# Align captions below Bootstrap responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap and working on a home page. I'd like to have a banner going across the page (in a fluid container) with an image containing three items. I'd like to have a caption for each item (just below) but I'm not sure how to align it if the banner image is responsive and fluid. See image below:

[image]

So I need the text to always be underneath the three items pictured in the banner. What's the best (cleanest) way to do this?

Edit: Here is a fiddle. http://www.bootply.com/0n433n0oFE
As you can see, when I shrink the screen width, the image doesn't expand vertically to accommodate the long text on the left.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried so far in a fiddler?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh  I added a fiddle for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Gotcha, totally misunderstood that the three items are part of the background image.